# Does installing mysql-server include mysql-client as well?

Tags: apt, server, mysql

I was wondering what the difference is between mysql-server and mysql-client and came upon [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6962890/what-is-the-difference-between-mysql-server-and-mysql-client) explaining the difference. I was curious if installing mysql-server also included mysql-client. So, after creating a fresh AWS Ubuntu instance, I ran which `which mysqld` and `which mysql` to confirm  nothing came preinstalled with the AWS instance, and sure enough both commands returned nothing. However, after running `sudo apt install mysql-server`, when I ran `which mysql` and `which mysqld` they both returned something: `which mysqld` returned /usr/sbin/mysqld and `which myself` returned /usr/bin/mysql, suggesting that my installation of mysql-server installed **both the client and the server**. Is that accurate? As I mentioned, the stack overflow post I  visited earlier indicated they were distinct pieces of software, so I'm wondering why installing mysql-server would install the client as well?

Comment: Yup. Check for yourself. `sudo apt install -s mysql-server`

Comment: +1 for the clarification of the difference between `mysql` and `mysqld`.  I am not sure why mysql-server installs the client part as well but it looks logical: how can you use the server without at least one client?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are separate pieces of software, but installing `mysql-server` installs `mysql-client` as well, because you can use `mysql-client` to connect to the server, even over localhost. If you look at the [package listing](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/mysql-server) for mysql-server, you will see it depends on [mysql-server-8.0](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/mysql-server-8.0), which depends on [mysql-client-8.0](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/mysql-client-8.0), causing `apt` to install the client as well.